# Getting this error in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue') in WebDriverIO cucumber Framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cucumber, webdriver-io

I am new to webdriverio and try to run the basic tests in cucumber framework, When I am running  the test browser is loading and opening the website but its failing in the second step (Input username and password )
I have tried looking for a solution but didnt get anything. Could you please help me to solve this

GitHub: https://github.com/Jyoti2190-Test/webdrieriopractice/tree/master

Note: Have already tried adding browser.pause(3000).

Please find the code below
**Feature File**

```
Feature: To test the login functionality in "The Internet Herokuapp"

    Background:
        Given the user is on login page
    Scenario: The one where user logs in using valid credentials

        When the user enters username as "tomsmith" and password as "SuperSecretPassword!"
        And clicks on login button
        Then the user must navigate to secure area page displaying a message "You logged into a secure area!"

    Scenario Outline: The one where user logs in using invalid credentials
        When the user enters username as "<username>" and password as "<password>"
        And clicks on login button
        Then the user must remain on login page displaying a message "<errorMessage>"
        Examples:
            | username | password | errorMessage |
            | james | SuperSecretPassword! | Invalid username! |
            | tomsmith | SuperPassword! | Invalid password! |
```

**PageObject File (login.page.js)**

```
class LoginPage {
    get userNameTextBox() { return browser.element('#username'); }
    get passwordTextBox() { return browser.element('#password'); }
    get loginButton() { return browser.element('button[type="submit"]'); }

    get loginPageElement() { return browser.element('div[class="example"] h2'); }
    get messageElement() { return browser.element('#flash'); }

}

export default new LoginPage();
```

**Step.js**

```
import { Given, When, Then } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
const LoginPage = require('../pages/login.page');
const SecurePage = require('../pages/secure.page');

Given('the user is on login page', function () {
    browser.url("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");
    expect(browser).toHaveTitle('The Internet');
});

When('the user enters username as {string} and password as {string}', function (username, password)     
{
    browser.pause(6000);
    LoginPage.userNameTextBox.setValue(username);
    LoginPage.passwordTextBox.setValue(password);
});

When('clicks on login button', function () {
    LoginPage.loginButton.click();
});

Then('the user must navigate to secure area page displaying a message {string}', function (successMessage) {
    expect(SecurePage.secureAreaElement).toExist();
    expect(SecurePage.secureAreaElement).toHaveTextContaining('Secure Area');

    expect(SecurePage.messageElement).toExist();
    expect(SecurePage.messageElement).toHaveTextContaining(successMessage);
});

Then('the user must remain on login page displaying a message {string}', function (string) {
    expect(LoginPage.loginPageElement).toExist();
    expect(LoginPage.loginPageElement).toHaveTextContaining('Login Page');
    expect(LoginPage.messageElement).toExist();
    expect(LoginPage.messageElement).toHaveTextContaining(errorMessage);
});
```

```
**Error Log**  

[0-0] Error in "0: When the user enters username as "tomsmith" and password as "SuperSecretPassword!""
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue')
    at World.<anonymous> (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\features\step-definitions\/step.js:13:31)
    at World.executeAsync (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:325:27)
    at World.testFrameworkFnWrapper (..\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\test-framework\testFnWrapper.js:45:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Object.wrapPromiseWithTimeout (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\time.ts:56:10)
    at Object.run (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\user_code_runner.ts:86:16)
    at Object.run (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\step_runner.ts:50:20)
    at TestCaseRunner.invokeStep (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:130:12)
    at TestCaseRunner.runStep (..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:307:20)
    at ..\Documents\WebDriverIO_Cucumber_Project\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\test_case_runner.ts:210:36
```

```
"keywords": [],
  "author": "Jyoti Singhal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.16.11",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.12",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.16.12",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.12",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.16.11",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.11",
    "chromedriver": "^97.0.0"
```

Comment: what is the version of nodejs and webdriverio you are using?

Comment: @Raju Node Version :  v16.13.1  & webdriverio cli: 7.6.12

Comment: Sure I will add it soon

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution , changed required to import for all import statements and changed element. Selector as well

[image]

Comment: You should include your changed code for clarity as well.